# Centos server hanged due to postfix/sendmail spam emails

Tags: apache, sendmail, centos7, email-spam, postfix-mta

My centos server is running web applications in LAMP stack. A couple of days back, the server was not responding for about 10 mins and I got http response failure alert from my monitoring tool. When I checked the httpd error log I found a huge log entry (~12000 lines) related to sendmail.

```
14585 sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied
```

The server ran out of memory and not responding.

```
14534 [Fri Aug 19 22:14:52.597047 2016] [mpm_prefork:error] [pid 26641] (12)Cannot allocate memory: AH00159: fork: Unable to fork new process
14586 /usr/sbin/sendmail: error while loading shared libraries: /lib64/librt.so.1: cannot allocate version reference table: Cannot allocate memory
```

We are not using sendmail in any of our application. How can I stop this attack in future?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This error in your logs does not look like it is caused by too many emails. Anyway, you should disable postfix service if you are not using it.

Comment: @DusanBajic the log file has been flooded with this line "sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: Permission denied" . There are around 12k lines with the same log over a short time of around 5mins.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I have no comment facilities; it looks like one of your website pages is vulnarable for code injection, finding out where and what page may be a huge job. Focus on input (forms) variables. Always sanitize input variables before using them! P.s. php uses "sendmail", even if you use Postfix, it will use a sendmail binary to send mail and the sendmail binary will redirect it to Postfix. If your forms work well and the 12k error log lines come out of the blue, then I would think someone is trying to inject code through your website (happens all the time by the way).

Comment: Thanks! Is there any easier way to find out which form/website is responsible for this issue? What log file do I have to refer for this? I have around 10 websites most of them in wordpress.

Comment: First of all, make sure your Wordpress (including used themes) installation is always up to date, that alone already may fix the problem. Further: check your Apache log files *_access.log and *.log for each domain. The location of these log files depend on your Apache configuration. Under BSD they reside in /var/log/httpd/*